# Setting region color after applying SLIC-segmentation

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, scikit-image

I'm working on object detection issue using SLIC segmentation. I would like to create animation which will represent each iteration of implemented algorithm. For this purpose I am searching for quick way to set region color. One way it's using property, called coords, returned by skimage.measure.regionprops, which returns coordinates list belonged to region. After that you're able to change color of each pixel, but it takes some time. Do you know any faster way of setting color for region?

Comment: Sharing the code you've written would help answering your question. You can edit your question to add it :)

Comment: Also, have a look at `skimage.color.label2rgb`; btw, please consider sharing your code as an example for the scikit-image gallery!

Comment: This is actually that thing I was searching for. It's enough to provide label's array with regions I'd like to highlight. Juan, I'm infinitely grateful for your advice.